# How to add third party jars without version to the maven repo

Tags: maven

How can I add third party jars with out a version no. to the local maven repo? I am trying to build my application using maven 3.0.4. It has dependency on 3 third party jars which resides in my local disk. These jars doesn't have a version no. Here is the MANIFEST.MF file of one jar

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: builder
Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_15
Revision: 105598
```

plz help me to solve this maven dependency issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to do this by modifying your local repo by hand, but you may want to look into the [`System`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) scope.  It lets you specify the path to the jar you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Every single artifact in maven, including plugins and archetypes, must have a version. Just pick any version and stick to it. `1.0` sounds fine. Or even better - look deeper, maybe these JARs *do* have some version after all?

Comment: Other than MANIFEST.MF file, where can we find the version no.?